# не работает добавление класса addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему не происходит добавление класса через addClass? Есть noUIslider, я ему через span добавил проценты ниже, при прокрутке слайдера спану должен добавлять класс, который будет менять цвет процентов, но этого не происходит.

HTML

```
   <div id="slider">
                  <div class="scale">
                      <span class="scale0">0%</span>
                      <span class="scale10">10%</span>
                      <span class="scale20">20%</span>
                      <span class="scale30">30%</span>
                      <span class="scale40">40%</span>
                      <span class="scale50">50%</span>
                      <span class="scale60">60%</span>
                      <span class="scale70">70%</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.scale {
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    color: slateblue;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.highlight {
    color: #ef0000;
}
```

Javascript

```
function update_slider_percent_scales (percents) {
    var ar = [
        { percent:  0, classes: '.scale .scale0' },
        { percent: 10, classes: '.scale .scale10' },
        { percent: 20, classes: '.scale .scale20' },
        { percent: 30, classes: '.scale .scale30' },
        { percent: 40, classes: '.scale .scale40' },
        { percent: 50, classes: '.scale .scale50' },
        { percent: 60, classes: '.scale .scale60' },
        { percent: 70, classes: '.scale .scale70' }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        var item = ar[i];
        if ((Math.abs(percents - item.percent) < 0.0001) || (item.percent <= percents)) {
            $(item.classes).addClass('highlight');
        }
        else {
            $(item.classes).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Попробуйте, например, вместо `'.scale .scale0'` просто `'.scale0'`

Comment: К сожалению, результат такой же, addClass не происходит.

Comment: как вызывается данная функция? какое значение `percents` приходит?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, например, вместо `'.scale .scale0'` просто `'.scale0'`

Если важно указывать родительский див тогда можно так:

```js
function update_slider_percent_scales (percents) {
    var ar = [
        { percent:  0, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale0' },
        { percent: 10, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale10' },
        { percent: 20, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale20' },
        { percent: 30, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale30' },
        { percent: 40, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale40' },
        { percent: 50, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale50' },
        { percent: 60, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale60' },
        { percent: 70, parent: '.scale', children: '.scale70' }
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        var item = ar[i];
        if ((Math.abs(percents - item.percent) < 0.0001) || (item.percent <= percents)) {
            $(item.parent).children(item.children).addClass('highlight');
        }
        else {
            $(item.parent).children(item.children).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    $('#cl').click(function () {
       update_slider_percent_scales(40);
    });
});
```

```css
.scale {
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    color: slateblue;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.highlight {
    color: #ef0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
                  <div class="scale">
                      <span class="scale0">0%</span>
                      <span class="scale10">10%</span>
                      <span class="scale20">20%</span>
                      <span class="scale30">30%</span>
                      <span class="scale40">40%</span>
                      <span class="scale50">50%</span>
                      <span class="scale60">60%</span>
                      <span class="scale70">70%</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div id="cl">DEMO</div>
```

Comment: По клику добавление класса происходит, но при прокрутке слайдера, он так же не добавляет. P.S. добавил ваш див демо для проверки.

Comment: как вы вызываете функцию и какие параметры ей передаете?

Comment: Знаете я новичок во всем этом и да я забыл вызвать саму функция, только проблема в том, что я не знаю как грамотно ее вызвать, вот сам слайдер, если вы знаете как можно передать ему эту функция, был бы признателен.
`var slider = document.getElementById('slider');



noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [30],
    handles: 1,
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 70
    },

    format: wNumb({
  decimals: 1,
  thousand: '.',
  suffix: '%',
 })
  
    
});`